# Why is Godot not showing + using my folders + files

Tags: godot

I am relatively new to Godot, and have started a roguelike game project with a few friends of mine. Recently, we decided to change the repository, in an attempt to add room for newer projects and more people.

After the transition over, files are no longer showing in the Godot file explorer.

I have tried changing the code in the .gd files using notepad and recloning the new repository. I do not think it is an issue with the files themselves, though, as my friend is running the same code without any issues.

We have the same Godot version (3.4.4), code, and both moved over at the same time. I'm still relatively new to Godot, so this may be something obvious I'm missing, but nothing online is helping.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Godot file explorer". Are you saying the project does not show in the Project Manager? Or are you saying that project is there, it opens, but then none of the files appear in the FileSystem? Or something else?